# does stirring honey make it less viscous?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, bond, home-experiment

After making some research, I found that crystallized honey does get less viscous as we stir it, so is it the same thing with pure honey or not? and also if not could we use the Zahn cup experiment to test for the viscosity of crystallized honey or no?

Answer (score 4):

A very good reference to the rheological properties of honey, both in a liquid and a crystallized state, is https://www.intechopen.com/books/honey-analysis/rheological-properties-of-honey-in-a-liquid-and-crystallized-state.

The summary is that some varieties of honey may be slightly thixotropic (shear thinning), but that honey can be generally considered as newtonian. My impression is that the concentration of sugars, or the amount of water, is the chief cause of viscosity type. After all, a solution of sugars (glucose, fructose and even some sucrose) will have a viscosity which is quite newtonian (linear shear force vs shear rate), and it will increase as the concentration increases, until you can just visualize the honey plowing up in front of the blade as the honey gets more concentrated and viscous.

Minor constituents in the bee barf are probably also thickening, just like minor constituents in saliva.

Another possibility is that stirring a viscous material like honey develops some heat with a small temperature rise which causes a drop in viscosity.